# Как реализовать вход по Pin-коду (отпечатку пальца)

Tags: java, android, безопасность

Скажите, как можно реализовать функционал ввода пароля (PIN четырехзначный) при запуске приложения? 
А также сделать возможность вместо PIN использовать биометрию. 
Гуглил, но там только реализация в виде вызова в onRestore(), да и то, не слишком понятно

Comment: Под Android не пишу и вообще мимопроходил, но наверное вам нужен этот [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html). Вот довольно развернутый пример: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html

Answer (score 3):

Сканер отпечатков пальцев поддерживается *Android M*.
Краткий алгоритм его реализации таков:

1.Прописываете разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
```

2.Получаете экземпляр класса `FingerprintManager` и вызываете метод `authenticate()`.

3.Реализовываете UI для аутентификации с помощью отпечатков пальцев, используя стандартное изображение отпечатков пальцев.

Вот [мануал в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication) и [пример](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html).

Comment: Очень полезный материал, спасибо!
А что касается функционала PIN-кода, можете что-нибудь подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

Нагуглил пример, в котором в приложение имплементируется стандартный сервис Android KeyGuard, который привязывается к текущим настрокам безопасности Дройда. Перенести в свое, думаю, не сложно
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConfirmCredential